# Neovim colorscheme W18: invalid character in group name

Tags: plugins, lua, neovim, color-scheme, kali-linux

I downladed a colorscheme for neovim with packer but when I open a fili with neovim or neovim itself I am getting a

W18: invalid character in group name

error

P.S. Using Lua BTW

I couldn't find any documentation on this error in the github or anywhere in the web besides updateing, but in Kali neovim does not update to 0.8 or >0.8, if anyone knows how to update or manually solve this errror for kali specifically, please leave a comment.

Comment: It may help to include information about the contents of the colorscheme